# loading data dynamically in custom component

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Am new in Sencha, so forgive me if am going through wrong way.

Am having a scenario under which we have created a **Custom Widget Component 'tableComponent'**, and included in my app.
Custom Widget is working perfectly with static data,but have to make it dynamic after loading it an different view using xtype.

Attaching Codes :

**Custom Widget Code**

```
Ext.define('tableComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'tableComponent',
    config: {
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<table>',
                    '<tpl for="rows">',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<tpl for="columns">',
                        '<td>{html}</td>',
                        '</tpl>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '</tpl>',
                '</table>',
            '</tpl>'
        ),
        data: [
               {

                   rows: [
                       {
                           columns: [
                               { html: 'column 1' },
                               { html: 'column 2' },
                               { html: 'column 3' }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           columns: [
                               { html: 'column 1' },
                               { html: 'column 2' },
                               { html: 'column 3' }
                           ]
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {

                   rows: [
                       {
                           columns: [
                               { html: 'column 1' },
                               { html: 'column 2' },
                               { html: 'column 3' }
                           ]
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
    }
});
```

Added in another view (namely : viewMain) under items array :

```
{
    xtype : 'tableComponent',
    height : '100%',
    width : '100%'  
}
```

On complete loading of the above View ,would like to set data dynamically for specific xtype component.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to dynamically modify a container's `data` you can use the method `update()`. Outlined in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-update)

Additionally, to find a `component` you can either traverse the hierarchy using `up()` **or** `down()` or use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` to query by `xtype` or `itemId`.

Here's a code snippet

```
var comp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tableComponent')[0];//returns an array of matching     
                                                         //components so I'm grabbing 
                                                         //the first
comp.update(newDataHere);
```

[I added working fiddle to demonstrate](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qg)

Comment: Thank You WeekDev for giving such a good explanations !! comp.setData() works for me instead of comp.update(); Cheers !!